# React/formik - How to validate minimum age > 18 in yup

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

My date validation is currently like this

```
birthday: yup.date().required(`Please enter your child's birthday/due date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the field value into a Date

```
yup.date()
        .nullable()
        .test("birthday", "Please enter your child's birthday/due date", function (value) {
                    return differenceInYears(new Date(), new Date(value)) > 18;
                  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in the validation file, define a function that will calculate the age:

```
function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday;
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Then in your validation block, use test and call that function in it like this:

```
birthday: yup.date().required(`Please enter your child's birthday/due date`).test("birthday", "Only above 18", function(val) {
        return calculateAge(new Date(val)) > 18;
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `date-fns` library for dates.

```js
import { sub } from "date-fns/fp"

const yourValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  dob: yup
    .date()
    .required()
    .max(sub({ years: 18 }, new Date()), "User must be over 18 years old"),
})
```